# How do I make parts of a C++ program loop?

Tags: c++, loops

I've made a Rock, paper, scissors C++ program, but I'm having a hard time trying to get it to loop. In the program, it counts wins and losses (ties don't count) and when it ties, it continues until a win/loss. When a win/loss occurs, either variables (pWins for Player Wins or pLosses for Player Losses) is incremented. It asks if the user wants to play again, and if the user says no, the program ends and shows a score.

My problem is how to get the program to loop in cases of ties and the user choosing to continue the game. I know I should put some do-whiles, but i'm not sure how to write them.

```
if( pInput == ROCK && cInput == ROCK )
{
    std::cout << "You tied with me!" << std::endl;
}
else if( pInput == ROCK && cInput == SCISSORS )
{
    std::cout << "Drats! You win!" << std::endl;
}
else if( pInput == ROCK && cInput == PAPER )
{
    std::cout << "Hah! Here comes the Hug of Death!" << std::endl;
}
else if( pInput == SCISSORS && cInput == SCISSORS )
{
    std::cout << "Looks like we tied!" << std::endl;
}
else if( pInput == SCISSORS && cInput == ROCK )
{
    std::cout << "Hah! I smashed you, so I win!" << std::endl;
}
else if( pInput == SCISSORS && cInput == PAPER )
{
    std::cout << "Drats! You win!" << std::endl;
}
else if( pInput == PAPER && cInput == PAPER )
{
    std::cout << "Drats! We tied!" << std::endl;
}
else if( pInput == PAPER && cInput == SCISSORS )
{
    std::cout << "Hah! I win, because I'm a scissor!" << std::endl;
}
else if( pInput == PAPER && cInput == ROCK )
{
    std::cout << "Drats! You gave me the Hug of Death!" << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "You won " << pWins << " times, and lost " << pLosses << "times.";

}
```

Comment: This would be significantly easier to do with a lookup table and a `switch` statement. The two selections could be combined into a single value, like `state = pInput << 2 | cInput` for example. Then you can test against all possible matches using a singular `switch` testing vs. all reasonable outcomes. As for loops, have you ever used `for` or `while`?

Comment: Hard to suggest something useful without seeing rest of the code.

Comment: Where are `pWins` and `pLosses` being set? Similarly, do you have a `pTies` variable? It seems like you would want a `pTied` variable (just a `bool`). Any time the result is a tie, set it to true; any time the result is _not_ a tie, set it to false. Then, you just wrap the whole thing in a `while` loop. `while (pTied) { ... }`.

Comment: I agree with @RSahu - the code you showed has nothing to do with your question! Show us something that needs to be in a loop (and if you feel the huge tragic list of if-else statements needs to be in a loop, pretend it's all in a single function so we don't get distracted with that scary monster).

Comment: Just put `while (true)` around the whole thiing. At the bottom of the loop, ask if the user wants to play again. If they say no, use `break` to exit the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, you can use `while`, `for` and `do-while` to iterate in a loop.

You will have to determine the "exit" criteria for the loop.

Here's an example:

```
bool can_continue = true;
while (can_continue)
{
  cout << "Do you want to continue?";
  std::string answer;
  getline(cin, answer);
  if (answer = "no")
  {
    can_continue = false;
  }
}
```

**Edit 1:**
You can simplify your program by checking for ties:

```
if (pInput == cInput)
{
    std::cout << "You tied with me!" << std::endl;
}
else
{
  // Check for winning combinations.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right in thinking of using a do while loop. You could try something like this:

```
do {
    //your program
} while(condition);
```

This way your program would run once and then continue running if your condition is still true. The condition in your case would be some form of a game over boolean.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the general structure:

```
int main() {
    do {
        pInput = getPlayerInput();
        cInput = getComputerInput();
        result = checkResult(pInput, cInput); // here you could put your code, and you 
                                              // could also set pWins and pLosses here

        if (result == tie) {
            playAgain = true;
        } else {
            playAgain = askPlayAgain();
        }
    } while (playAgain);

    print_results();
}
```